# htmlpage.window.navigate opens a new page or new tab on every click

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

In My Silverlight application I've a button click, each time when I click it calls this code

```
 private void Help_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_blank");
  }
```

But my problem is for each click it is opening a new tab or window in ie browser.

How could I prevent that by just refreshing the 1st opened page or tab with that url. 
I want to Prevent the opening of multiple tabs every time.

(eventually I want to pass a dynamic url to navigate 
ex: 1st time www.stackoverflow.com/questions
    2nd time I want to refresh the same opened page with www.stackoverflow.com/answers).

Comment: First click should open a new window and next click should refresh the same opened window or tab which is already opened.

Comment: You can't make this if i'm not wrong. The Problem is `How you will check whether your URL opened or not in Browser.? `

Answer (score 1):

Insead of `_blank Use _self`

**For Example:**

Don't Use This

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_blank");
```

You Just Use this

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_self");
```

Possible Values:

- _blank - the target URL will open in a new window
- _self - the target URL will open in the same frame as it was clicked
- _search - the target URL will open in the search pane
- _top - the target URL will open in the full body of the window
- _parent - the target URL will open in the parent frame-set

As Per your comment one alternative Way you can make it. If you wish you can use this.

```
private void Help_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        // Checking the Condition
        if (Session["hasvalue"].ToString() == "Clicked") // Second click onwards current TAB itself
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_self");
        }
        else // First Time it will be opened in New TAB
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_blank");
        }

        // Assign this value to session
        Session["hasvalue"] = "Clicked";
}
```

Hope you may get some idea.,

Comment: Problem is if you open my site and click a link then it will open a new tab with that link (which is good).But If you click again on my site click link, it will open a new tab (other than the 1st one). so for each click it opens a new tab. And I don't want to open a new tab for each click. I want a new tab should be opened on 1st click. And the 2nd click should check whether a new tab opened or not, and if it opened, it should just refresh it.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve using

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/"), "xyz");

where xyz is a random word. it can be replaced with any word

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to open a new tab, remove `"_blank"` from your `Uri` constructor. So change

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_blank");
```

to

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
```

See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) explanation of target for more information.

`"_self"` is the default but you could use

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"), "_self");
```

to make things more explicit.

Comment: Sam, Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to open the link in a new window or tab, not in the same window as it was clicked. _self (the default one) will open the link in the same page. I tries _parent and _top, but those are also opening the link in the same page.

Comment: But you say "But my problem is for each click it is opening a new tab or window in ie browser." What is the problem then? You are in a browser other than IE and it's opening the tab in IE?

Comment: Problem is if you open my site and click a link then it will open a new tab with that link (which is good).But If you click again on my site click link, it will open a new tab (other than the 1st one). so for each click it opens a new tab. And I don't want to open a new tab for each click. I want a new tab should be opened on 1st click. And the 2nd click should check whether a new tab opened or not, and if it opened, it should just refresh it.

Comment: You loose a handle of the new tab once you open it. I am not sure there is a way to modify another tab from a different tab.